# Android CalendarView class cannot be found

Tags: java, android, eclipse, calendarview

Im designing the xml format for a calendar to be used in an app, but I cant get the calendar to show in the **graphical layout** shower.

Instead I get the following 'error':

> The following classes could not be found:
>   - CalendarView (Change to android.widget.CalendarView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

The min SDK version for this project is 14 and its target version is 15.

Here is my **XML** code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/top"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button android:id="@+id/dash"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:maxWidth="200dp"
                    android:maxHeight="10dp"
                    android:text="DASHBOARD"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="10px"
                    android:paddingTop="10px"
                    android:text="Calendar"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/plusButton"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top"
            android:maxHeight="300dp" />

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/infoScroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/calview">

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxHeight="100dp">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </ListView>

            </ScrollView>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/infoScroll">
            <Button android:id="@+id/todayButton"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:text="Today"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/listButton"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dayButton"
                    android:text="List"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/dayButton"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="Day"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/monthButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dayButton"
            android:text="Month"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/PeopleButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="People"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>



        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Mark as an answer if this solved your issue :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

you might be previewing your screen on Android Target 16. Try using Android Target 15 for Graphic Layout Editor (android icon on the top, in ADT 20). Looks like there is issue with Android Target 16.

NOTE: You **don't** need to set the project target just the target in the graphical layout editor.

Comment: Your answer saved me from continuing to believe that I just couldn't use the DatePicker element for some reason.  I thought "Can't find the DatePicker class??", and then I found this post. DatePicker works just fine. Thanks again.