# Date picker is not displayed in the layout design?

Tags: java, android, datepicker, task

[image: date picker is not clear with it's own design]

When i drag and drop the datepicker in the layout design 
It shows an error message like this,

> **The following classes could not be found:**

- CalendarView (Change to android.widget.CalendarView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- DatePicker (Change to android.widget.DatePicker, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

What i have to do to solve this issue.

Comment: upload your code as well

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android CalendarView class cannot be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365959/android-calendarview-class-cannot-be-found)

Comment: After changing the api level it worked..

Comment: but why it is not working with api level 16 and above.

Comment: I just trying a task remainder app,so i need to select the date as well as time, how to use the date time picker,can i use these two components in the same layout or another layout.???

Answer (score 1):

Date picker will pop up just month, day, year set of fields with up and down arrows. It won't really work though, unless you create your own dynamic set and cancel buttons. Once you click one of them to bring up the keyboard, you cannot get rid of it. You'll likely want to use the full date picker widget.

To properly use the date picker, make a new one in your activity.java instead:

```
    new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                d,
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
```

Make that trigger from a button.

If you want to try what happens if you pull it out of the widget palette like you did, change the android target version to something like 10 and you might be able to see it. The errors you are getting are likely due to just the view you have in eclipse not being able to render them, not necessarily the widget itself. Also try to see if you can get it on a phone to look at it too.

Answer (score 0):

i think in your `LinearLayout` orientation is not set. set `orientation` to vertical for your layout.Other wise put your xml code

Answer (score 0):

Just run the code, it will be visible on device. You can see it in XML also by just changing the xml target.

NOTE: You don't need to set the project target just the target in the graphical layout editor.