# Android Studio DatePicker/TimePicker rendering/nullpointerexception problems?

Tags: java, datepicker, android-studio, timepicker

Something like calendar view works perfectly fine, but I'm not too sure why it can't find what it needs for DatePicker or TimePicker.

I'm not too experienced with Android so forgive me if this question is too simple.

build 135.1629389

For DatePicker:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:484)
    at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:2484)
    at android.widget.YearPickerView$YearAdapter.getView(YearPickerView.java:132)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:627)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:527)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:331)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:688)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:677)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:677)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:815)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

For TimePicker

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.hardware.input.InputManager.populateInputDevicesLocked(InputManager.java:691)
    at android.hardware.input.InputManager.getInputDevice(InputManager.java:204)
    at android.view.KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.java:334)
    at android.widget.TimePickerSpinnerDelegate.getAmOrPmKeyCode(TimePickerSpinnerDelegate.java:1035)
    at android.widget.TimePickerSpinnerDelegate.generateLegalTimesTree(TimePickerSpinnerDelegate.java:1133)
    at android.widget.TimePickerSpinnerDelegate.<init>(TimePickerSpinnerDelegate.java:175)
    at android.widget.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:89)
    at android.widget.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:76)
    at android.widget.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:82)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:128)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:401)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:329)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:688)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:677)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:677)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:815)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78842

Comment: Hmm, I just run the app on my phone and DatePicker is shown. I presume the solution is like this one but for Android Studio instead of Eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365959/android-calendarview-class-cannot-be-found

Comment: Ok, turns out I had to downgrade the API version for it to show in the 'Design' tab. I downloaded API 19 and changed the 'Android Layout to use when rendering layouts in the IDE" to API 19. I presume there's a bug with API 21

Answer (score 2):

For those who experience the same issue with e.g. Android Studio and API 21, try to set `android:datePickerMode`. Nothing worked except this line. Note that it is new to API 21.

Answer (score 1):

Also appears that with API21 there is a rendering bug specifically with Date/Time pickers, and it appears this has been an ongoing issue for a few revisions.  As you say above dropping back to 19 or less solves it.  I didnt try 20.

See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82712